# Regex Searching in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using vim to do some pattern matching on a text file. I've enabled search highlighting so that I know exactly what is getting matched on each search and am getting confused.

Consider searching for `[a-z]*` on the following text:

```
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz987654321ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWQXZ
```

I expected this search to match zero or more consecutive characters that are in the range [a-z]. Instead, I get a match on the entire line.

Should this be the expected behaviour?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Have you tried `[a-z]+` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's matching the empty strings that occur after every character. It has no way of highlighting empty ranges, so it looks like everything is highlighted.

Try searching for `[a-z]\+` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Empty string matches `[a-z]*`... therefore this thing is matching everywhere. Perhaps you want to cut down some of the cases by doing `[a-z]+` (1 or more), or `[a-z]{4,}` (4 or more).

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting a match on the entire line, you're getting a match on every character. Your pattern also matches nothing at all, which is matched by every single character.